# From pointwise convergence to uniform: metrics

Tags: convergence, metric, measure-theory

Let $\mu_\theta$ be the limit of an empirical measure $\mu_{n, \theta}$. $\theta \in \Theta$ and $\Theta$ is a compact set. Morever, the maps $\theta \rightarrow \mu_{n, \theta}$ and $\theta \rightarrow \mu_\theta$ are continuous.

Let $d$ be a metric. I already proved that for all the $\theta \in \Theta$

$$d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \mu_\theta) \rightarrow 0 \text{ in probability}$$

and the rate of convergence depends obviously on $n$ but not on $\theta$.

Now, I need to prove that

$$\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}|d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \nu) - d(\mu_{\theta}, \nu)| \rightarrow 0$$

where $\nu$ is another measure.

Using the reverse triangle inequality, we have that

$$\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}|d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \nu) - d(\mu_{\theta}, \nu)| \leq \sup_{\theta \in \Theta}|d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \mu_\theta)| = \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \mu_\theta)$$.

However, since $d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \mu_\theta) \rightarrow 0 \text{ in probability}$ then $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta} d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \mu_\theta)$ should also converges to $0$. The supremum being just one of the thetas and I have already proved that all thetas will converge to 0.

I feel like I'm jumping to a conclusion here. Can somebody help?

Comment: There appears to be a notation error in your second and third equations:  $|d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \nu) - d(\mu_{n, \theta}, \nu)|$ is equal to zero all the time.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I edited my post.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62518/convergence-of-tent-function to see the problem with this logic.  In that example, the "tent functions" $f_n$ are continuous on the compact set $[0,1]$, and converge pointwise to $0$.  It is true that for each $n$, there is an $x$ where the supremum $\sup_x |f_n(x)-0|$ is attained.  *But it isn't always the same $x$.*

Comment: So when you go to try to prove uniform convergence, given $\epsilon$ you have to produce an $N$ such that for all $n \ge n$ and all $x$, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$.  You can't say "well, use the $N$ corresponding to the $x$ where the supremum is attained", because that might be where the supremum for *one* of the $f_n$ is attained, but you need an $N$ that works simultaneously for all of them.

Comment: It's possible that the solution can be found from looking at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285958/weak-convergence-in-probability-implies-uniform-convergence-in-distribution-func.